# Select data from multiple tables owned by multiple schemas

Tags: sql, oracle

Limited skills with SQL so please bear with me :-)

I have an Oracle database with multiple schemas most containing a table called `C_USERNAMES`.

I wish to write a query that queries ONLY the schemas that contain a table called C_USERNAMES and return rows based on one or more of the column data.

I can run this from the SYS account.

Ideally I want to return the data as a single formatted report of a form (assume that `Name` and `Address` are column names in the `C_USERNAMES` tables) :

```
Schema   Name   Address
-----------------------
SCH001   Dave   Station Road
SCH006   Paul   Main Ave
etc
```

I know I need some sort of nested query or join / union but I cannot work out anything that gets this to work. I want the query to be smart in that it works out which schemas contain a table C_USERNAMES.

Thanks for any pointers and please forgive me if this is a basic question.

Comment: DBA_TABLES would be the starting point of finding schemas with a certain table name. BUT, as someone with limited SQL skills you really shouldn't be doing this as SYS

Answer (score 2):

This whole setup scares me.  You should never be running queries as `SYS`.  No one that has limited SQL knowledge should be going anywhere near `SYS`.  Having tables in different schemas that contain information that you'd want to combine together in a single query implies a significant normalization problem.  And having someone with limited SQL skills building dynamic SQL just adds to the set of issues.

That said, you can use dynamic SQL to construct the query you want.  Something like this may be close to what you want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_usernames
  RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
  l_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT t.*,
                   rank() over (order by owner) rnk
              FROM dba_tables t
             WHERE table_name = 'C_USERNAMES'
             ORDER BY owner)
  LOOP
    IF( t.rnk = 1 )
    THEN
      l_sql := 'SELECT name, address FROM ' ||
               t.owner || '.c_usernames';
    ELSE 
      l_sql := l_sql ||
               ' UNION ALL ' ||
               'SELECT name, address FROM ' ||
               t.owner || '.c_usernames';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  OPEN l_rc 
   FOR l_sql;

  RETURN l_rc;
END;
```